# Server error while editing

Tags: bug

I am getting this error while editing post:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Runtime Error

Description: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.
```

What is happening I am unable to understand?
 Please, Can anyone tell me what is going on?

Comment: Had the same issue - lasted about 10 min, but seems to OK now.

Comment: Yep, SE wide error, it's affected all pages. We'd need to wait a few seconds for Nick to fix it.

Comment: The app works for some reason

Comment: @mplungjan, the app uses SE API which is up and running.